# How to select the record with two different postcode in ms access with sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm new in sql script. I'm currently trying to write a sql script to select the record that with two different postcode from a table in ms access with sql query. For some reason this is just not working for me.

Example:
I have the following table resident_postcode :

```
Postcode      Name
1001          Alan
1002          James
1003          Alan
1004          Merry
1001          Merry
```

I write a sql script to select the name that have 2 different postcode and looking for the output like following:

```
Name
Alan
Merry
```

I have tried to run the following script but for some reason this is just not working in MS Acess:

```
SELECT a.Name
FROM resident_postcode a
WHERE 1 < (SELECT count(b.Postcode) FROM resident_postcode b  WHERE b.Name= a.NameGROUP BY b.Name)
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong with my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no repetition of same postcode for any name then you can have names with two post codes as below

```
SELECT NAME FROM RESIDENT_POSTCODE
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING COUNT(POSTCODE)=2
```

But if any postcode can be specified more than once (for example **1001** is specified more than once for **Alan**) then you need to use below query:

```
select name from (
 SELECT distinct NAME, postcode FROM RESIDENT_POSTCODE) 
group by name 
having count(*)=2
```

if you want all names having two or more than 2 postcode then use below query:

```
select name from (
     SELECT distinct NAME, postcode FROM RESIDENT_POSTCODE) 
    group by name 
    having count(*)>=2
```

Comment: @KeithT . . . This won't work in MS Access so it is rather surprising that you accepted it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff actually I wasn't sure regarding the answer since I didn't use Access as database in more than decades. But with some searching I though it would work fine. Is distinct in having clause is the culprit?

Comment: MS Access does not support `count(distinct)`.

Comment: Now it is wrong.  That is why I addressed the comment to the OP.

Comment: At last I have checked the result in ms access. Can't have distinct with count or having.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```sql
SELECT [Name]
FROM resident_postcode
GROUP BY [Name]
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want *2 or more* different post codes, then you can use:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM RESIDENT_POSTCODE
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING MIN(POSTCODE) <> MAX(POSTCODE);
```

If you want *exactly* two, then you can use:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NAME, POSTCODE
      FROM RESIDENT_POSTCODE
     ) AS NP
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```